# Add time stamp to an imageCollection of Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, mapping, timestamp

On the [Mapping over an ImageCollection](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_mapping) documentation page, in order for adding time stamp the function is written as

```
    // This function adds a band representing the image timestamp.
var addTime = function(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start'));
};
```

However, on the very next page of the documentation, [Reducing an ImageCollection](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_reducing), the function is written as:

```
// This function adds a band representing the image timestamp.
var addTime = function(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start')
    .divide(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
};
```

#### Question:

So, why the division does not exist in the first function? What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example adds a timestamp that represents the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 at 00:00:00 GMT (Unix epoch). The second example converts milliseconds to years (floating point) since epoch. The second example performs a linear fit between time and the EVI vegetation index. Having time in units of years makes the slope easier to interpret.